# How to multiply to separate dataframes and apply a function to get a new dataframe with the result in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, rowwise

I have two data frames. One of it has codes (1 or -1) for different IDs.

```
data.1 <- read.csv(text = "
IDs qt1 qt2 qt3
pl1 -1 -1 -1
pl2 1 -1 1
pl3 1 1 1
pl4 -1 -1 -1
pl5 1 1 1
pl6 1 1 1
pl7 1 -1 1
pl8 1 1 1 
pl9 -1 -1 -1
pl0 -1 -1 -1
")
```

And have another dataframe, with three variables, parameters and estimates.

```
Data.2 <- read.csv(text = "
variable parameter estimate
varA a0 2.3
varA a1 0.859
varA a2 0.527
varA a3 0.774
VarB b0 19.08
VarB b1 0.412
VarB b2 0.022
VarB b3 0.448
VarC c0 5.4
VarC c1 0.492
VarC c2 0.094
VarC c3 0.971
")
```

For each IDs, I need to estimate the value of each variable. For example, for pl1 and VarA, the value I need to calculate is a0 + (a1*qt1) + (a2*qt2) + (a3*qt3).

The expected result for each of the IDs would be somethin like this:

[image]

Of course this is a mock up example, and I have hundres of IDs, and Variables. Therefore, I'd need some automatic way to do this. I was exploring options with `dplyr::rowwise` and trying to write a function, but couldn't find a way to make a sensible code.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the qt values by row and insert a 1 as the first value, split the estimates by variable and then multiply and sum:

```
qt_vals <- split(cbind(qt0 = 1, data.1[-1]), f = data.1$IDs)
vals <- split(Data.2$estimate, f = Data.2$variable)

sapply(vals, function(x) sapply(qt_vals, function(y) sum(x * y)))

     varA   VarB  VarC
pl0 0.140 18.198 3.843
pl1 0.140 18.198 3.843
pl2 3.406 19.918 6.769
pl3 4.460 19.962 6.957
pl4 0.140 18.198 3.843
pl5 4.460 19.962 6.957
pl6 4.460 19.962 6.957
pl7 3.406 19.918 6.769
pl8 4.460 19.962 6.957
pl9 0.140 18.198 3.843
```

Note that you have `pl10` in the image but `pl0` in the example data which is the source of the discrepancy between the image and the result above.

Comment: thanks so much for the help. It works perfect. Super efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a cross join merge between the data frames after slight reshaping to wide format. Then, run your specified calculation without any loops.

```
# ADD COLUMN + RESHAPE WIDE
wide_data.2 <- reshape(transform(data.2, var_letter=gsub("[a-z]", "", parameter)), 
                       idvar = "variable", v.names = "estimate",  drop = "parameter",
                       timevar = "var_letter", direction = "wide")

# CROSS JOIN MERGE + CALCULATION
merge_data <- within(merge(wide_data.2, data.1, by=NULL), {
        calc_value <- estimate.0 + (estimate.1*qt1) + (estimate.2*qt2) + (estimate.3*qt3)
})

# RESHAPE WIDE
wide_merge_data <- reshape(merge_data[c("IDs", "calc_value", "variable")], 
                           idvar = "IDs", v.names = "calc_value", 
                           timevar = "variable", new.row.names = 1:nrow(data.1),
                           direction = "wide")
wide_merge_data 

#    IDs calc_value.VarA calc_value.VarB calc_value.VarC
# 1  pl1           0.140          18.198           3.843
# 2  pl2           3.406          19.918           6.769
# 3  pl3           4.460          19.962           6.957
# 4  pl4           0.140          18.198           3.843
# 5  pl5           4.460          19.962           6.957
# 6  pl6           4.460          19.962           6.957
# 7  pl7           3.406          19.918           6.769
# 8  pl8           4.460          19.962           6.957
# 9  pl9           0.140          18.198           3.843
# 10 pl0           0.140          18.198           3.843
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Parfait. Great solution too. I'd prefer the other one because it has less coding for me.

Comment: Understood. Though long winded this solution is three lines without a single or nested loop (`for` or *apply*). Last `reshape` was your requested format. Ideally, you want to keep everything in [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) or long format. Also, this solution clearly shows your original formula for code readabilty and maintainability, and easy change of arithmetic. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, I really like that the original formula is readable. I will use this solutions for other tasks I have. Thanks so much for your time and knowledge!